# What is a transfer function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

If:

- $N$ is a set of nodes in a program dependence graph, which is a graph with two type of edge
- $L$ is a lattice of security levels

What does the following mean:

"For every $x\in N$, a so-called *transfer function* $f_{x}:L\rightarrow L$ must be defined". Of specific interest is what the notation $f_{x}$ represents, and understanding the purpose/definition of a transfer function.

Furthermore, in this context what does this mean:

"The theory demands that all $f_{x}$ are monotone."

I am having a hard time determining what "monotone" means, possibly because I don't understand the notation $f_{x}$.

The text I'm referring to can be found in the third and fourth paragraphs of section 4.2 of [this document](https://pp.info.uni-karlsruhe.de/uploads/publikationen/hammer09ijis.pdf). It is related to the computer science concept "monotone data flow analysis framework."

Comment: The key expression here is "in this context". There isn't enough of it.

Comment: The sentence "For every $x\in N$, a so-called *transfer function* $f_x:L\rightarrow L$ must be defined" sounds as if he's saying he's about to tell you what a transfer function is.  In another context, a transfer function is what the Laplace transform of an input function gets multiplied by in order to get the Laplace transform of the output function. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @joriki Any hints on what would help to flesh out the context?

Comment: A link to the text, more of the surrounding text, how this transfer function is used, what "the theory" refers to, what $L$ is, why $\mathcal{L}$ never appears again after you introduced it, ...

Comment: @joriki I added some extra details, including a link to the text. All of this is very new to me, so I'm still working out what's relevant and what's not. $\mathcal{L}$ was used by the paper, but I feel in this instance it was misleading, so I removed it.

Comment: this "transfer function" is not related to laplace transform or convolution. it is more an injection on lattice elements ? there lattice elements being the security levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $f_x$ denotes a separate function specified at each node $x$. For each $x$, the transfer function $f_x$ of node $x$ must be monotone. On this, see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#Monotonicity_in_order_theory). The condition for monotonicity is $x\le y\implies f(x)\le f(y)$. If you think of lattices as algebraic structures rather than partial orders, see, again, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28order%29#Connection_between_the_two_definitions) for the connection.

As regards the "transfer function": This term is being used in a way specific to this field; you'll need to understand the theory to understand why they call it that; it doesn't correspond to any general mathematical usage. It sounds as if the reference [$29]$ should explain the term, but I don't know, since it's not freely available.